# How long is a rotation?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

In the Season 2 finale of Star Wars: Rebels, Captain Rex said he could get to Malachor in "two rotations".

I assume this means *"...of a planet"* but if so **which planet and how long is it?**

Comment: When they talk about a "rotation" when they're on or near a planet, they invariably mean one *local* day/night cycle. When they talk about a rotation when they're in space, they almost certainly mean one *standard* rotation (e.g. 24 hours, the same as the rotational period of Corsucant).

Comment: The term "rotation" is used in [this gallery](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/the-gathering-episode-gallery) to mean 19 standard days, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general rule of thumb in Star Wars is that when they talk about a "rotation" without any further context, they're usually referring to one [Standard Day](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Standard_day/Legends), the amount of time that it takes for Coruscant to perform one complete turn around its axis.

On other occasions, they may refer to a "rotation" to mean one *local* day/night cycle. Depending on the planetary system this can range from just a few hours up to hundreds of days  In this [example](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/the-gathering-episode-gallery) (Panel #7) a "rotation" is described as being ***19*** standard days(!).

In the context of this episode, Rex is probably referring to a Standard Day.